# How to select checkboxes in cakephp and sending email

Tags: cakephp

I created a page using cakephp and I have checkboxes for every field (the page contains list of patients and for every patients I have checkbox). 
Now I want to select few patients and send email to selected patients. Here my question is how to link the selected patients to email tab.

It will be helpfull if you can give elaborated answer. 
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('User.patient_email_ids][', array('multiple' => 'checkbox', 'options' => $checkbox_list));?>
```

and your $checkbox_list array variable should contain values like following:

```
$checkbox_list = array(
                       [abc@def.com] => patient1,
                       [ghi@jkl.com] => patient2
                      );
```

and you can pass $this->request->data['User']['patient_email_ids'] to the Mail component in $to(list of all recipients) variable.